# Undeclared namespace prefix "soapenv" error while using web service consumer

Tags: mule-studio, mule4, mule-component, sap-ariba

I am using web service consumer in Mule4 and after configuration and deployed the application and triggered the target ARIBA SOAP service in logs I see below error:

> org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader: Undeclared namespace prefix "soapenv" at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,14]

When I explored the error I see it is an issue at target system end :], please let me know whether it is end system thrown error or any pointers on what would cause this issue.

[Link to Oracle documentation about Ariba Adapter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/ariba-adapter/invalid-soap-message-response-error.html) (*Cloud > Cloud Platform > Integration Generation 2 > Using the SAP Ariba Adapter with Oracle Integration Generation 2 > 5 Troubleshoot the SAP Ariba Adapter > Invalid SOAP Message Response Error*)

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared seems pretty clear. It is an issue on SAP Ariba side. The solution is also shared in the same page:

> The error message is as follows:

```
<fault xmlns="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
<errorCode>OSB-380001</errorCode>
<reason>java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Error parsing 
envelope: most likely due to an invalid SOAP message.: Undeclared namespace prefix 
"soapenv" at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,14] </reason>
```

For some reason Ariba doesn't seem to be declaring the SOAP XML namespaces in its responses.

> If you receive the invalid soap message response error or some other invocation error from Ariba, you must enable the following property in the Ariba sand box.

```
Application.Messaging.Channels.Util.IncludeNameSpaceDetailsInErrorResponse
```

You have to follow the instructions to configure Ariba to include the namespaces in responses.